# joining multiple dataframes without having same columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In pandas how can i join three Dataframes, if all of them does not have same columns? for two dataframes having matching columns answer is there, but if we want to join a, b, c dataframe a nd b has same column and b and c has same column then can i join a, b, c if yes please explain how ?

Comment: in mysql we can do this easily , can we do this using pandas dataframes

Comment: select 
#  a.StoreID,
#       d.Name StoreName,
#       b.SupplierId,
#       b.ProductID,
#       c.Name,
#       a.BatchID,
#       b.Batch,
#       b.DateExpiry,
#        b.PackSize,
#       a.Quantity PresentStockInHand,
#        b.SaleUnit,
#       b.UnitPrice,
#3       b.CostPrice,
#        b.MRP
#from 
# pos.tbl_store_inventory a
#  inner join
# pos.tbl_batch_detail b on a.BatchID=b.BatchID
#  inner join
# pos.tbl_product c on b.ProductID=c.ProductID
#  inner join
# pos.tbl_store d on a.StoreID=d.StoreID
#    where a.StoreID='SID';

Comment: can i join these tables using pandas dataframes